# string of digits and how to transform it to string of 0 and 1 depending on condition

Tags: c#

I'm given a task: Given a string of digits, you should replace any digit below 5 with '0' and any digit 5 and above with '1'. Return the resulting string.
Here is my solution

```
static string FakeBinary(string number)
        {
            string output = "";
            int integerRepresentation = int.Parse(number);
            int[] digitsArray = new int[number.Length];
            for (int i = digitsArray.Length; i <digitsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int currentDigit = integerRepresentation % 10;
                integerRepresentation /= 10;
                if (currentDigit > 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[i] = 1;
                }
                else if (currentDigit < 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[i] = 0;
                }
                output += digitsArray[i];
            }
            return output;
        }
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong, please help.

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger and step through your code. This is an absolutely paramount skill to develop when learning to program. Here's a hint...look at how your for loop is initialized. It isn't doing what you want it to.

Comment: well now i get some output but it's wrong, i'll try figure out why

Answer (score 1):

- Inital loop value is the mistake

  ```
     class Program {
       static string FakeBinary(string number) {
         string output = "";
         int integerRepresentation = int.Parse(number);
         int[] digitsArray = new int[number.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < digitsArray.Length; i++) {
           int currentDigit = integerRepresentation % 10;
           integerRepresentation /= 10;
           if (currentDigit > 5) {
             digitsArray[i] = 1;
           } else if (currentDigit < 5) {
             digitsArray[i] = 0;
           }
           output += digitsArray[i];
         }
         return output;
       }

       public static void Main(string[] args) {
         FakeBinary("4567");
       }
     }
  ```

Comment: please look at my solution and check indices of digits array, they should be like this digitsArray[digitsArray.Length - i - 1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, check it out if interested

```
static string FakeBinary(string number)
        {
            string output = "";
            int integerRepresentation = int.Parse(number);
            int[] digitsArray = new int[number.Length];
            for (int i = 0;i <digitsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int currentDigit = integerRepresentation % 10;
                integerRepresentation /= 10;
                if (currentDigit > 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[digitsArray.Length - i -1] = 1;
                }
                else if (currentDigit < 5)
                {
                    digitsArray[digitsArray.Length - i - 1] = 0;
                }
                output += digitsArray[i];
            }
            return output;
        }
```